# How do you extract text matching a pattern in XPATH?

Tags: regex, xpath, pattern-matching

I have data that looks like this:

```
<value>v13772   @FBst0451145:w&lt;up&gt;1118&lt;/up&gt;; P{GD3649}v13772@
v13773  @FBst0451146:w&lt;up&gt;1118&lt;/up&gt;; P{GD3649}v13773@</value>
```

How can I process this string in XPATH to extract any and all @FBst####### numbers?

I know of the xpath matches() function... but that only returns true or false.  No good if I want the matching string.  I've searched around but cannot find a satisfactory answer to this problem, which is probably really common.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In addition to the good answer by Michael Kay, if you want to use only the `replace()` function, then use**:

```
replace(.,'.*?(@FBst\d+).*','$1')
```

**The result is**:

```
@FBst0451145
@FBst0451146
```

**And if you only want the numbers from the above result, use**:

```
replace(replace(.,'.*?(@FBst\d+).*','$1'),
          '[^0-9]+', ' ')
```

**This produces**:

```
 0451145 0451146
```

Comment: Thanks! but your solution gave me FBst0451145:w&lt;up&gt;1118&lt;/up&gt;; P{GD3649}v13772@
FBst0451146.
I solved the problem using replace(.,'.*?(@FBst\d+).*','$1 ','m')
Thanks!

Comment: The context node is different.  It actually is data($y/value) from an xquery query.  I paraphrase it to '.' for simplicity.

Comment: The new snippet works very well!  Can I ask why the nested set of parenthesis?  replace(.,'.*?(@FBst\d+).*','$1') seems to work the ame

Comment: @JD, You are right -- I was playing with a more complex RegEx when I arrived at this solution -- this is how the outermost brackets remained there. Replaced with the simpler Regex in my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I Assume you can also use XQuery. The [get_matches()](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_get-matches.html) function from the [FunctX](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/) module should work for you. [Download](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/download.html) the file which supports your version of XQuery. Then import the module whenever you need its functionality.

```
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xq";

functx:get-matches(string-join(//text()),'xyz')
```

Comment: Interesting.. I've never heard of this before.  Is this the way this problem is usually solved?

Comment: I'm not sure why such functionality is not availably in XPath/XQuery by default, but FunctX adds a lot of great functions. I guess that because XPath/XQuery is often used within another context (e.g., called from within another programming language), some functionality is expected to be present already.

Comment: Thanks Sicco!  I looked over their website and couldn't find any instructions on how to apply these libraries.  Do you mind throwing a bone this way? :)

Comment: Did you download one of the files on the [download page](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/download.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
tokenize(value, '[^0-9]+')
```

which should return the sequence of tokens separated by sequences of non-digits.

Comment: Thank you Michael!  This isn't shown here, but this is one of many <value> elements, others of which have other numbers, which this solution doesn't cover.  I'm looking for a
    !'FBst[^0-9]+'
kind of regular expression, to extract only the FBst values.  I'm not sure if this pattern is possible in this context though.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With help from Dimitre, a working regex is:

```
replace(.,'.*?(@FBst\d+).*','$1 ','m')
```

Although it doesn't work unless a newline separates each target string, it will do for now.

Thanks everyone!